# Is there a way to use a previous Chrome Version?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, chromium

i'm trying Electron and so far i'm loving it.

For work purposes, i need to use a previous Chrome Version in my app (49 would be ideal).

Is there a way to use a given (previous) version in my app?

Thanks a lot

Comment: 49? That's from March 2016 o.O

Comment: @Andreas - My guess is they need to run on XP or Vista. v49 was the last version of Chrome that ran on XP/Vista.

Comment: Thank you very much. May i know where Electron gets the chrome package?
Is there a specific folder? Or it refers to the latest version i got on the system?

Comment: Electron currently uses Chromium's GN build system. It tracks dependency versions through the DEPS file (latest stable: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/8-x-y/DEPS).

Comment: Also note that using older Chromium versions leads to a plethora of security vulnerabilities that have been fixed in later versions (https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1224/product_id-15031/Google-Chrome.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an outdated version of Chromium (it's not Chrome) in Electron is likely to be a non-trivial task. Electron combines Node.js and Chromium into a **single** executable ([source](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/about#updating-dependencies)). You can't just download a different version of Chromium and put it in a directory somewhere and have it get used.

If you're lucky, doing this "just" means building Electron from source. Electron is open source. The repo is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/electron/electron). The repo goes back to 2013, so it covers the period when Chrome v49 was released (exactly four years ago, March 2nd 2016). In theory, you find the right point in the history of the repo, check out that version, and build it.

Of course, that means you don't have access to any improvements in Electron in the last four years.

If you wanted to try to get Electron's latest source to work with an old version of Chromium, it'll be a lot more work. You'd need to:

1. Clone the Electron project locally.
2. Find the [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/build_instructions.md) for Chromium for the release you want.
3. Update your local Electron source to use that version of Chromium.

   - Dealing with any issues that arise because the Chromium interfaces Electron uses may have changed.
4. Deal with any issues that causes in the Node.js side of things. You may need to get an old version of the Node.js source as well, from about the same time as the Chromium version you're running.

   - Again dealing with any issues that arise because the Node.js interfaces Electron uses may have changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very clear. I'll try to do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Google removes older versions from Package Archive whenever an update is released.

The only way is to maintain your own repository of these installation packages.

Or you could download packages from third party given you understand security threat you might expose yourself to.